# CDO check if email was received/valid

Tags: email, asp-classic, response, cdo.message

I want to add users with bad/invalid emails to a table in my database. (why: professors add students that may have written their emails down wrong, and we want to contact the professors with a report asking them to verify)
Is there something like a delivery receipt to see which were actually received: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/can-i-get-cdo-messages-to-return-a-read-receipt.html

and then add emails to my table if the response from mail server is anything other than received.

I would like to receive this information right when the script is run, but if this is not possible - can you think of a way to do this scripting-wise? I could run it once a week. It seems like VRFY is disabled on a lot of mail servers so I was unsure whether this was a valid option: http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/excerpt/sendmailckbk_chap01/index1.html?page=2

My code sends emails out fine; I just need to add this functionality.

Comment: The way I have done this in the past is to use JMail POP3 to scan the sending address mail box for delivery failure notifications, but it is not very reliable as delivery failures can be in many different formats, and you need to distinguish between failures and out of office replies. One of the systems I used in the past worked by unsubscribing if there were 3 consecutive replies in a 6 week period.

Comment: I'm using an account for sending the bulk emails. In CDO I specify an ReplyTo parameter to ensure all replies go to a different account. This way i can ensure that only error messages bounce back into the bulk account. There I use a filter to delete all error messages that are not permanent (quota etc..). This way only a few are left and i check them on a regular basis (by hand...).

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but we already have the manual method setup. We have have an email box like what @stare suggested.